# how to skip a portion while debugging a recursive function with gdb

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

Here is a function in my program

```
void
quicksort (int *num, int p, int r, int june)
{
  int q, bbc, ccd;
  if (p < r)
    {
      call++;
      q = partition (num, p, r, june);//<--I want to skip this call in gdb session
      bbc = q - 1 - p + 1;//<-- and want to continue execution step by step from here
      quicksort (num, p, q - 1, bbc);
           ccd=r-q+1;
      quicksort (num, q + 1, r, ccd);
    }
} //since it is a recursive function each time quicksort is called partition is also executed I want to focus my debugging only to quicksort
```

If you notice it calls another function  partition in between.While running in a gdb session
I want to skip the gdb showing me steps of parition i.e. I know function partition is correct so do what partition does and then jump to next instruction

```
     bbc = q - 1 - p + 1;
```

and in my debugging session do not show info about partition.
So how can I skip that part and continue debugging quicksort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for a *step over*.

> Step Over is the same as Step Into,
>   except that when it reaches a call for
>   another procedure, it will not step
>   into the procedure. The procedure will
>   run, and you will be brought to the
>   next statement in the current
>   procedure.
>
> - Quote from http://www.developerfusion.com/article/33/debugging/4/

In GDB, you do this by issuing the `next` command.
When you are running the `q = partition (num, p, r, june);` line in gdb, type `next` and it will just execute the partition function without going into its code in detail.

You can find detailed information about stepping in gdb in this [reference](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_38.html).

Comment: Silveria what you mentioned is not happening it is in fact going inside partition function that is why I posted this question.

Comment: @Registered User What are you using, `next` or `step`?

Comment: Silveria man I was wrong in my previous comment.Kudoos to you I have been able to debug the recursive function I was busy since morning. +1 for this.

Answer (score 2):

```
b <line number>
```

will set a break point

```
c
```

will continue until the next breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

You can either set a breakpoint for the line after `partition`:

```
b <line number>
```

Then use `c` to continue until the breakpoint.

Or you can use `n` to skip over the `partition` call (that is, type `n` when you reach the `partition` call, and it will skip the body of the function).

Or you can type `finish` to exit the `partition` function after entering it.