# Change of behavior when passing int array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing an array as an argument in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763861/passing-an-array-as-an-argument-in-c)
>   [Sizeof an array in the C programming language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975128/sizeof-an-array-in-the-c-programming-language)

Can you please explain the output of the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void foo(int array[])
{
    int size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);    
    cout<<size<<endl;
}
int main()
{
    int array[] = {1,2,3};

    int size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
    cout<<size<<endl;
    foo(array);
    return 0;
}
```

The corresponding output is:

```
3
2
```

Both the code inside **foo()** and inside **main()** looks similar to me so as to produce the same output, but it does not, can you please explain why?

Comment: ARhgh, bad learning material strikes again. No array is being passed here.

Comment: Summary: Whenever you pass an array as a parameter you need to pass the length as well. Even better would be to just use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not passing the *array* into the function, you are passing the *pointer* to the array.

That means, in the function `foo()`, the result of `sizeof(array)` is the size of a pointer to an array of char, *not* the size of the array itself, so the function is effectively doing this:

```
cout << sizeof(int *) / sizeof(array[0]);
```

In this case size of `int *` is 8, size of int is 4, so you are getting an output of 2 from the function.

Comment: The array elements are `int`, not `char`. Doesn't change the point, but you should still correct it. (`sizeof(char*) != sizeof(int*)` is allowed.)

Comment: @DanielFischer, right, thanks! For some reason I thought it was 'char array[]' instead of 'int array[]' in OP's post

Answer (score 4):

```
void foo(int array[])
```

in C or C++ you cannot pass arrays by value, so the above declaration is interpretted as:

```
void foo(int * array)
```

Consider passing the array by reference:

```
template <size_t N>
void foo( int(&array)[N] )
{   
    cout << N << endl;
}
```

Comment: That's not really an answer, since the question was "why are the results of the output different?"